# Single-word-request: a bottom vertex

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the word for the point where two lines come together, if that point is at the bottom of the whole?

For example, in a cone (so this isn't exclusively lines), pointed down, what would you call the point?

***Vertex*** is a possibility as it means

> • each angular point of a polygon, polyhedron, or other figure.
>
> • a meeting point of two lines that form an angle.

However, it also means

> • the highest point; the top or apex

which is in fact the opposite of the meaning I seek, and could lead to confusion.

**Nadir**, as the *lowest point*, could work but it makes no reference to anything coming together and, I believe, only used figuratively except for in reference to astronomy.

**Use in a sentence:**

> • We need to put a gutter at the ---- of the (inverted) roof, where the two sides slope down to each other.
>
> • The font-designer recommended that his student make the capital M's ---- sharper. 
> <sub>*(Note: I choose M rather than V because the lower angle of the M is not in fact the lowest part of the M—it is not the base or the bottom. It's primary identity is as a vertex, except that vertex also indicates apex.)*</sub>

*Edit and possible answer:*

> ***Juncture***, a place where things join

which carries no meaning of *top*.

All definitions from NOAD.

Comment: What's wrong with "lowest point"?

Comment: Antonyms of "apex":  Base, bottom, nadir.

Comment: But for your roof situation the usual term is "valley".

Comment: @HotLicks While those are the antonyms of apex in any thesaurus, they make no reference to coming to a point

Comment: perhaps 'rock-bottom'

Comment: I've added a second example to make the word-request more general because I am not only looking for the point where two surfaces come together.

Comment: For the *M* example, I would use *trough*. On second thought, *tooth* would be better.

Comment: Your second example is nonsense.

Comment: @HotLicks lolz.

Answer (score 3):

Consider ***valley***:

> **2** :  a low point or condition
>
> **3 b** :  the place of meeting of two slopes of a roof that form on the plan
>   a reentrant angle
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valley)</sub>

The term does invoke metaphorical imagery, but is also a roofing term as indicated by the definition.

Here is a description of a *butterfly roof* using the term:

> A **butterfly roof** (sometimes called a **V roof** or **London roof**) is a form
>   of roof characterised by an inversion of a standard roof form, with
>   two roof surfaces sloping down from opposing edges to a *valley* near
>   the middle of the roof.
>
> [image]
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_roof)</sub>

Comment: I've added a second example to make the word-request more general because I am not only looking for the point where two surfaces come together.

Comment: I provided two definitions for *valley*, and the first of the two satisfies both examples.

Comment: I would consider a slope a surface. I would also notice that the definition refers specifically to roofs.

Comment: *a low point or condition*

Comment: @jxh - For your roof example "valley" is definitely the correct term.  This is the term used by roofers and architects and the like.  Your other example is screwed up, so I can't tell what it should be.

Comment: @HotLicks: Sorry, I hadn't noticed you provided *valley* in a comment when I posted.

Comment: @jxh - Not a problem.  I would have posted it as an answer, but I was too lazy.

Answer (score 1):

***[Base](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/base):***

> - the bottom part of an object, on which it rests, or the lowest part of something.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- We need to put a gutter ***at the base*** of the (inverted) roof, where the two sides slope down to each other.

Answer (score 1):

> **Depression**

According to MW: A *depression* is "a place or part that is lower than the surrounding area"

If you don't want to use *nadir*, *depression* is the word that comes first to mind. As previously stated here, you can also use *base* or *bottom*, but I think this serves your sentence best.

1. We need to put a gutter at the depression of the (inverted) roof, where the two sides slope down to each other.

Comment: While depression gives the ... impression, at least to me, of a more rounded low point, I appreciate this suggestion